# Google DialogFlow unable to detect Intents

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am developing a voice chatbot using Dialogflow. I have integrated it with TeleGateway. It is unable to detect intent and keeps repeating its prompt. In test during development also it is not able to detect intent. I am following all steps given in documentation. I have also published the app in a dev environment.
Am I missing any step in its development/deployment.
--sanksh

Answer (score 0):

One potential issue could be ML Classification Threshold. If it is too high it will be more difficult to detect intents. Also, make sure you include more than 10 similar training phrases for your intent. Finally, check the training phrases of prompt message maybe it has overlapping phrases with your intent. 
You can debug and check the details either using Diagnostic Info or logs. If the above suggestions do not fix your problem, then you should provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The diagnostic info shows very high level of speechRecognitionConfidence - 0.8472007, but still the intent is not being captured and conversation initiated. I have added more than 10 training phrases for training. Is there a way to mark, highlght the trigger in the training phrases which can help in intent detection?

Comment: Can you update your question with some examples and visuals?

Comment: The diagnostic info is : {
  "responseId": "eff374d8-6bb1-4d51-bc1a-2dba64c6ed0a-83ffff32",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "I would like to create my profile",
    "speechRecognitionConfidence": 0.97705114,
    "parameters": {},
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "outputAudioConfig": {
    "audioEncoding": "OUTPUT_AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16",
    "synthesizeSpeechConfig": {
      "speakingRate": 1,
      "voice": {}
    }
  }
}  but the intent is still not being captured. After adding the training phrases, I am training the model manually and re-publishing the application.